# How to set api routes in a nodejs udp server?

Tags: php, node.js, api, sockets, routes

Is it possible to set different routes on an udp server like on a http server?

I want to implement a simple nodejs server to call it in php like this.

```php
"udp://" . $host  . "/api/" . $apiVersion . "/myEndpoint";
```

Itried this

```js
var PORT = 1337;
var HOST = '127.0.0.1/api/v1/somethig';

var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

server.on('listening', function() {
  var address = server.address();
 console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ':' + address.port);
});

server.on('message', function(message, remote) {
 console.log(remote.address + ':' + remote.port +' - ' + message);
});

server.bind(PORT, HOST);
```

with the route in HOST I got the folowing error.

```
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 127.0.0.1/api/v1/somethig
←[90m    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26)←[39m
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
←[90m    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.callback (dgram.js:289:12)←[39m
←[90m    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:17)←[39m {
  errno: ←[32m'ENOTFOUND'←[39m,
  code: ←[32m'ENOTFOUND'←[39m,
  syscall: ←[32m'getaddrinfo'←[39m,
  hostname: ←[32m'127.0.0.1/api/v1/somethig'←[39m
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTTP, the 'path' part of your URL gets sent to your server on the first line.

While the `udp:` scheme seems valid (although I didn't find any official document detailing it), I don't think there's a mapping between the 'path' part and anything that the client would send you.

So broadly speaking, if you (or someone) uses the `udp:` scheme, there's no agreed upon or standard that documents what to do with this, so I doubt you'll get that segment submitted to you in any way.

Each protocol/scheme has to explicitly define what to do with many segments of the URI. A raw UDP or TCP socket doesn't really send any sort of data until you explicitly tell it to. Similarly you also won't know server-side what host was used to connect to you, whereas with HTTP the expectation is that this goes in the `Host` header.